# Second order ODE systems should be equivalent to first order systems but DSolve gives error with second order

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I'm trying to solve a physics problem using DSolve, and I've been getting varying degrees of success depending how I write down the equation.

Here is what worked:

```
DSolve[
  {v'[t] == -g - b/m v[t], x'[t] == v[t], x[0] == h, v[0] == v0}, 
  {x[t], v[t]}, t] // ExpandAll
```

and

```
DSolve[
  {v'[t] == -g - b/m x'[t], x'[t] == v[t], x[0] == h, v[0] == v0}, 
  {x[t], v[t]}, t] // ExpandAll
```

but these give me an error:

```
fall = 
  DSolve[
    {x''[t] == -g - b/m v[t], x'[t] == v[t], x[0] == h, v[0] == v0}, 
    {x[t], v[t]}, t] // ExpandAll

fall = 
  DSolve[
    {x''[t] == -g - b/m x'[t], x'[t] == v[t], x[0] == h, v[0] == v0},
    {x[t], v[t]}, t] // ExpandAll
```

and the error says that "the function v appears with no arguments."

I'm confused because 1) I'm pretty sure all of my `v`s are written with its argument `t` and 2) I don't understand why the simple change from `v'[t]` to `x''[t]` causes an error. Shouldn't Mathematica know that v'[t] == `x''[t]` since I specified that `v[t] == x'[t]`?

And why do I only get an error when changing that first `v'[t]` to `x''[t]`, and not when I change the `v[t]` to `x'[t]` as seen in the first two equations?

Comment: Works fine on MMA `11.3`.Try clear the kernel: ``ClearAll["Global`*"]; Remove["Global`*"];``

Comment: I was using the ClearAll command, but not the Remove one. Using both fixed the problem, thanks!